# Some contraction property for bounded self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Problem: For bounded self-adjoint operator $A,B$ on a same Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, prove $\left\|e^{iA} - e^{iB}\right\| \leq \|A-B\|$.

This problem has a hint: use mean value theorem to the function $t \to \left\langle e^{-itB}e^{itA}x,y\right\rangle$ on $[0,1]$ for $x,y$ in $\mathcal{H}$. When I use mean value theorem, I got 
$$\left\langle e^{-iB}e^{iA}x,y\right\rangle - \langle x,y\rangle = \left\langle i(A-B)e^{-it_0B}e^{it_0A}x,y\right\rangle.$$ Then I have no idea to go further, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not right, but you can write
$$\dfrac{d}{dt} \langle e^{-itB} e^{itA} x, y \rangle
= \langle (-i e^{-itB} B e^{itA} + i e^{-itB} A e^{itA}) x, y\rangle
= \langle i e^{-itB} (A-B) e^{itA} x, y \rangle $$
which is different from what you wrote if $A$ and $B$ don't commute.
Next, estimate the absolute value.

Comment: I already  got it